# Extend distance from gpu to motherboard

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, gpu

Is there a way in increase the distance between the motherboard and the GPU but still keep it connected? Google is by far not helping at all (it gives me dual monitor search results for some reason) and haven't seen the question asked here as well. To mount a PC along a plane and keep parts separated, is it possible to have some sort of cable that would connect to the motherboard GPU slot and the GPU itself?

Comment: Is it possible? Yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is called a `PCI-E Riser` **or** a `Flexible PCI-E Extender`. Make sure you get a x16 one as well, to match the PCI slot on your motherboard. You can find them anywhere like here:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/PCI-Express-Extender-Flexible-Extension/dp/B008BZBFTG

They look like this: [image]

Comment: on a quick sidenote, does it affect performance in any way?

Comment: Nope! Not at all, it will only start to affect performance when you go a much longer length.

Comment: To be perfectly clear, both items are needed to perform this, right? The extender and the riser card.

Comment: No no, just that. I will edit my post to make it less confusing for others.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and probably annoying follow up questions. I will accept your answer and you've earned yourself a cookie. Kudos :)

Comment: Hahaha, glad I could help! - Thanks :)